# Regex to detect this pattern: something;something=something,something=something... for an unknown number of times

Tags: php, regex

***Explicit rules:***

1. The string has two parts, separated using a semicolon.
2. The first part is allowed to have alphanumeric characters, dashes, underscores and dots
3. The second part of the string contains key-value pairs where key is set to its value using an equality sign and the pairs are comma separated and we don't know how many times they're repeated beforehand

Examples:

- `blahblahblah;first=1,second=two`
- `bl.hbl-hbl_hbl4hbl4h;first=1,second=two,third=thr33`

The best I've come up with so far is `([A-Za-z1-9_\-\.]+);(((.+?)(?:,|$))+)` which is obviously far from correct. I am not good at writing regexps with lookaheads, lookbehinds, and other relatively advanced stuff in regex but I hope that a regex solution exists for this problem.

If regex engine matters, I am using the Perl-compatible regex engine in PHP 8.1

Comment: Your regex does work: https://regex101.com/r/46xDV6/1  what isn't it doing that you want?

Comment: @sniperd It is capturing ```second=two;third=thr33``` as one group while I want them to be captured separately. Also, it can capture unwanted things as well. For example, it can capture this: ```bl.hbl-hbl_hbl4hbl4h;first=1,ssssssssss``` which is clearly not formatted correctly

Comment: You said _"pairs are comma separated"_ but also that `second=two;third=thr33` should be two pairs. You can't have both. You also said _"has two parts, separated using a semicolon"_ but then you show us a string with three parts.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm terribly sorry. It was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the following regex:

```
^([\w.-]+);([A-Za-z]\w*=\w+(?:,[A-Za-z]\w*=\w+)*)$
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `^`: start of string
- `([\w.-]+)`: first string, made of alphanumeric characters, underscores, dashes and dots
- `;`: semicolon
- `([A-Za-z]\w*=\w+(?:,[A-Za-z]\w*=\w+)*)`: key-value pairs

  - `[A-Za-z]`: alphabetical character
  - `\w+`: sequence of alphanumerical characters
  - `=`
  - `\w+`: sequence of alphanumerical characters
  - `(?:,[A-Za-z]\w+=\w+)*`: non-capturing group with the optional next key-value pairs

    - `,`: comma
    - `[A-Za-z]`: alphabetical character
    - `\w+`: sequence of alphanumerical characters
    - `=`
    - `\w+`: sequence of alphanumerical characters
- `$`: end of string

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/uoQYv9/1).

Comment: You could write the first part as `([\w.-]+)` because `\w` also matches an underscore, and it does not have to be non greedy because the characters in the character class can not cross matching `;` Also note that `[A-Za-z]\w+` matches at least 2 characters. You could also omit the superfluous non capture group in the second part, like `^([\w.-]+);([A-Za-z]\w+=\w+(?:,[A-Za-z]\w+=\w+)*)$`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation of how the regex you provided works. Much appreciated.

Comment: There's always something to learn from you @Thefourthbird. The only issue I'm having with regex101 is that it looks like dash needs to be escaped inside the characters selection, probably because it attempts to catch a range.

Comment: @lemon In that case you can put it at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Looks definitely better, thanks a lot.

Comment: Was trying to make a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/KKs9VU/1) that matched all key-value pairs separately, exploiting `\G`. Although this one would match also key-value pairs in non-correct strings. Do you have any hint on how to prevent it?

Comment: @lemon Sorry, I did not see your comment. Did you mean something like this with `\G` ? https://regex101.com/r/h5rtP4/1

Comment: Yeah, it may only require an additional non-capturing group to make comma+potential key-value pairs optional, to match if only one key-value pair appears in the string, something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/h5rtP4/2). I've tried with lookarounds with no success for a bit of time, although looks like you nailed it.

Comment: Maybe if we do the positive lookahead right after the first alternative, it might be less steps when there are more key/value pairs. https://regex101.com/r/vT25lO/1